# Python : wildcard query in Elasticsearch

Tags: python, elasticsearch, wildcard, elasticsearch-dsl, elasticsearch-query

I want to query a field using wildcard in Elasticsearch but the problem is that the search string is stored in a variable and not available statically.
The intended query is :

```
body={"query": {"wildcard": {"Name": { "value" : "Vi?????" }}}}
```

where the search string "Vi" is not available at compile time. It will be given by user. Say it is stored in some variable str (= "Vi"). How should I formulate a query using str and "?"s   ?

Comment: Maybe you should elaborate the question. Are you concerned about NoSQL injection ?, or wan't to do prefix search ?

Comment: Do you have your query in a variable?

Comment: Yes. the search string is stored in a variable and I want to create a query with that string. Basically user should get results corresponding to the input given by him/her. Obviously I cannot write a static query. How should I proceed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use `+` concatenation in `python`.

And you need to escape double quotes. There are many ways to do this. I prefer `escaping double quotes as \"`

```
searchWord ="Vi";
query = "{\"query\": {\"wildcard\": {\"Name\": { \"value\" : \"" + searchWord + "?????\" }}}}";
print (query);
```

`searchWord` is something that you receive from the user. I hardcoded it.

`query` is the one you need to form. This is how I formed it `\"" + searchWord + "?????\"`

Please check and provide any information which I need to consider.

**EDIT:**

```
searchWord ="Vi";
x = 2;
query = "{\"query\": {\"wildcard\": {\"Name\": { \"value\" : \"" + "[a-z]{" + str(x) +"}" + searchWord + "?????\" }}}}";
print (query);
```

Comment: I am thinking of using a regexp instead of wildcard for writing an easier query. Is this the correct way of writing an expression?                                                                                  ```result = es.search(index="my-index", body="{\"query\" : {\"regexp\": {\"Name\": \" "+str+".*\" }}})" ```

Comment: You just need to replace `wildcard` by `regexp`

Comment: Thanks. The solution worked. But I have another problem (hopefully the last one) at hand. The regex should contain another dynamic variable- the number of characters that should occur before string matching starts.

Comment: For example a working query that I wrote was something like this :                                                            "[a-z]{2}"+searchWord+".*"                                           Here I'm anchoring my searchWord in such a way that it appears as a substring starting from exactly the 3rd character (beginning 2 chars can be anything). How should I formulate the above query with "2" also being an input variable?

Comment: Same escape sequence. Enclose by double quote and concatenate by +

Comment: The following code snippet works just fine :                                                                               ```result = es.search(index="my-index", body={"query" : {"regexp": {"Name": "[a-z]{2}"+str+".*" }}})```                                                                                                                       Can you help me to replace 2 with a variable (say num)? I'm facing errors when I try to do with escape sequences.

Comment: Of Course. My bad. should've typecast int to string. Thanks a lot. You've solved a lot of my problems.